# Free Pascal use for loop to determine visibility of component based on status of Date Component

Tags: delphi, for-loop, freepascal

My form contains some components whose naming follows a simple convention...

```
date1, date2, date3, date4, date5

check1, check2, check3, check4, check5
```

I need to be able to determine the visibility of the checkboxes based on the contents of the date fields, i.e. if a date is returned then the checkbox should be visible.

I'm trying to do this with the following code and everything compiles, but I'm failing to target the components, presumably because its trying to alter the variable rather than the component. Am I going about this in completely the wrong way?

```
var
  dateVar : variant;
  checkVar : variant;
  x : integer;

// Set visibility of checkboxes and docs
x := 0;
dateVar := 'area.Date' + IntToStr(x);
checkVar := 'area.Check' + IntToStr(x);

for x:=1 to 5 do
  begin
    if dateVar > '00:00:00' then // Does FPC support the != or not equal to context?
       checkVar.Visibility := False
    else
       checkVar.Visibility := True;
    end;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the components via FindComponent. In the example below Self as the Form is given as Owner.

```
Procedure SetChecks(AOwner:TComponent);
var
   x:Integer;
begin
for x:=1 to 5 do
  TCheckBox(AOwner.FindComponent('check' + IntToStr(x))).Visible :=
  TDateEdit(AOwner.FindComponent('date' + IntToStr(x))).Date <>StrToDateTime('00:00:00');    
end;
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetChecks(Self);
end;
```

Comment: Whilst you could do this, it would be way better in an array

Comment: @DavidHeffernan personally I'd prefer (Object)List for cases such as these, however, it appeared to me something too vast as answer here.

Comment: List is good. It's just an array with bells and whistles. Inherently it's just a container with sequential indexing, just like an array. In fact, Delphi lists are all mis-named. The term list should be used for linked list.